# Have different <p> tag value show up in a separate div when you click each separate section

Tags: javascript, html, sass

long time listener, first time caller. I am trying my hand at making an NHL draft chart, as I do some player evaluation and want a fancy looking place to put it all/I'm having a bit of fun while I learn SASS for the first time (it rocks, btw).

Codepen: https://codepen.io/trjwaugh/pen/abONgLm

```css
$desktop: 1000px;
$padding: 15px;
$borders: 15px;
$margin: 20px;
$logo-clip: polygon(70% 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 40% 100%);
$colors: ( ggold: #FFB81C, gold-light: lighten(#FFB81C, 40%), //buf, cbj, edm, fla, nsh
bblue: #002654, blue-light: lighten(#002654, 40%), ragsblue: #0038A8, ragsblue-light: lighten(#0038A8, 40%), leafblue: #00205B, leafblue-light: lighten(#00205B, 40%), rred: #C8102E, red-light: lighten(#C8102E, 40%), oorange: #F74902, orange-light: lighten(#F74902, 40%), starsgreen: #006847, starsgreen-light: lighten(#006847, 40%), yotesred: #8C2633, yotesred-light: lighten(#8C2633, 40%), burg: #6F263D, burg-light: ligthen(#6F263D, 40%), black: black);
@function color($color-name) {
  @return map-get($map: $colors, $key: $color-name);
}

@mixin desktop {
  @media (max-width: #{$desktop}) {
    @content;
  }
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 78px;
  height: 80px;
  float: right;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  #bg {
    clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    @include desktop {
      //suff to change re: responsiveness
    }
  }
}

main {
  #container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
  }
  section#sticky-main {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: $padding;
    border-radius: $borders;
    background-size: 100% 100%, 0% 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, $alpha: 0.2);
  }
  section#card {
    margin: 1em auto;
    float: right;
    padding: $padding;
    border-radius: $borders;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%, 0% 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, $alpha: 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in;
    transition: .5s ease-in;
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      li {
        strong {
          display: inline-block;
          margin-left: max(40px);
          margin-top: 10px;
        }
        img {
          display: block;
          width: 138px;
          height: 130px;
          float: right;
          @include desktop {
            //suff to change re: responsiveness
            width: 100px;
            height: 92px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    #report.one {
      margin: 1em auto;
      float: right;
      padding: $padding;
      margin-right: 20px;
      border-radius: $borders;
      background-size: 100% 100%, 0% 100%;
      box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, $alpha: 0.2);
      width: 90%;
      background-color: white !important;
      color: black !important;
    }
    #report.one:hover {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  section#card.gold:hover {
    background-color: color(ggold);
    color: white;
    background-size: 80.1% 10%, 20% 10%;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(100, 0, 0, $alpha: 0.2);
  }
  section#card.blue:hover {
    background-color: color(bblue);
    color: white;
    background-size: 80.1% 10%, 20% 10%;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(100, 0, 0, $alpha: 0.2);
  }
  section#card.red:hover {
    background-color: color(rred);
    color: white;
    background-size: 80.1% 10%, 20% 10%;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(100, 0, 0, $alpha: 0.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9969435508.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <section id="sticky-main">
            <div id="content"></div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">

          <section onmouseover="hover()" id="card" class="gold">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img src="logos/anaheim-ducks.png">
              </li>
              <br>
              <li>
                <strong>Bigname McLongnamington III <i style ="color: green;" class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Kitchener Rangers (OHL)</strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>height weight</strong>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </section>

          <section onclick="showReport()" id="card" class="red">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img src="logos/chicago-blackhawks-logo.png">
              </li>
              <br>
              <li>
                <strong>Bigname McLongnamington III <i style ="color: green;" class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Kitchener Rangers (OHL)</strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>height weight</strong>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="report-two" style="display: none;">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer accumsan est massa, quis hendrerit augue volutpat sed. Nam sit amet bibendum enim, eget suscipit odio. Donec risus odio, bibendum eget ipsum eget, bibendum congue est. Sed
                maximus lorem sit amet nibh condimentum viverra. Vestibulum sed quam fringilla, rhoncus eros et, imperdiet tellus. In nec nibh sollicitudin, pharetra purus vitae, consectetur mi. Curabitur laoreet finibus placerat.</p>
            </div>
          </section>

          <section onclick="showReport()" id="card" class="blue">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img src="logos/columbus -bluejackets-logo.png">
              </li>
              <br>
              <li>
                <strong>Bigname McLongnamington III <i style ="color: green;" class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Kitchener Rangers (OHL)</strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>height weight</strong>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="report" style="display: none;">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer accumsan est massa, quis hendrerit augue volutpat sed. Nam sit amet bibendum enim, eget suscipit odio. Donec risus odio, bibendum eget ipsum eget, bibendum congue est. Sed
                maximus lorem sit amet nibh condimentum viverra. Vestibulum sed quam fringilla, rhoncus eros et, imperdiet tellus. In nec nibh sollicitudin, pharetra purus vitae, consectetur mi. Curabitur laoreet finibus placerat.</p>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section onclick="showReport()" id="card" class="blue">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img src="logos/columbus -bluejackets-logo.png">
              </li>
              <br>
              <li>
                <strong>Bigname McLongnamington III <i style ="color: green;" class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Kitchener Rangers (OHL)</strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>height weight</strong>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="report" style="display: none;">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer accumsan est massa, quis hendrerit augue volutpat sed. Nam sit amet bibendum enim, eget suscipit odio. Donec risus odio, bibendum eget ipsum eget, bibendum congue est. Sed
                maximus lorem sit amet nibh condimentum viverra. Vestibulum sed quam fringilla, rhoncus eros et, imperdiet tellus. In nec nibh sollicitudin, pharetra purus vitae, consectetur mi. Curabitur laoreet finibus placerat.</p>
            </div>
          </section>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you look at the Codepen, you can see i have a bunch of sections, all will act as a card that a players draft info will appear, minus a paragraph blurb about them. There are a few things ive tried in terms of accomplishing my goal but essentially I want to be able to click on a players `<section onclick="showReport()" id="card"...` and have that players paragraph blurb appear in the sticky div on the left, changing based on which section card you click on. right now I have the players paragraph in a p tag within the section just for now, but im open to anything. I have a JS function on click in there for now but what I have tried so far required me to write a seperate hide() for each section (will be 31 total). Im looking for a method that will also allow me to only change the bio info and never have to adjust any code when I want to make edits to my draft chart. I hope I explained myself well enough, please tell me if I need to clarify.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @PedroLobito I actually found out why It wasn't working, totally bonehead reason so i just deleted it. Still green but I was actually right - just an error somewhere else. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add `this` to each `onclick` on sections to get the element itself anytime you click on them.

```
...
<section onclick="showReport(this)" id="card" class="blue">
...
```

Then, you can use `this` (now turned into el variable) to find the text and put into the `#content` element.

```
function showReport(el) {
  $('#content').text($(el).find('p').text());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked great, except i had to do .find('p') instead of .find('div p').

Comment: Nice! I edited the answer to match what you commented.